# Do I have to use SSL with Paypal? How do I set Paypal on Windows Azure?

Tags: ssl, paypal, paypal-ipn, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I am putting online an old web application I had running like 3 years ago.
Back then everything worked and Paypal's ExpressCheckout was set perfectly.

I really cannot remember what I was doing back then but now I put my app on Windows Azure. My app is written in ASP.NET MVC5.

The following piece of code might look familiar for those of you who implemented Paypal inside your apps and its probably taken from Paypal's documentation and used for posing to Paypal's server:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// HttpCall: The main method that is used for all API calls
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="NvpRequest"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string HttpCall(string NvpRequest) //CallNvpServer
    {
        string url = pendpointurl;

        //To Add the credentials from the profile
        string strPost = NvpRequest + "&" + buildCredentialsNVPString();
        strPost = strPost + "&BUTTONSOURCE=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(BNCode);

        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        objRequest.Timeout = Timeout;
        objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                myWriter.Write(strPost, 0, strPost.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CommonFuncs.Log(MyGlobals.LOG_FILE_DO_EXPRESS_CHECKOUT, e.Message);
            return null;
            /*
            if (log.IsFatalEnabled)
            {
                log.Fatal(e.Message, this);
            }*/
        }


        //Retrieve the Response returned from the NVP API call to PayPal
        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
        string result;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //Logging the response of the transaction
        /* if (log.IsInfoEnabled)
         {
             log.Info("Result :" +
                       " Elapsed Time : " + (DateTime.Now - startDate).Milliseconds + " ms" +
                      result);
         }
         */
        return result;
    }
```

Now, when I'm trying to POST (here)

```
using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    myWriter.Write(strPost, 0, strPost.Length);
                }
```

I am getting the following error message

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Does it mean that I have to purchase an SSL certificate? or is there something I just need to tweek on Azure so it will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @PP_MTS_Steven.
I can't remember the source on SO which gave me the solution. However, all I did was to put this two lines of code:

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        // allows for validation of SSL conversations
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Right here:

```
    public string HttpCall(string NvpRequest) //CallNvpServer
    {
        string url = pendpointurl;

        //To Add the credentials from the profile
        string strPost = NvpRequest + "&" + buildCredentialsNVPString();
        strPost = strPost + "&BUTTONSOURCE=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(BNCode);
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        // allows for validation of SSL conversations
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };


        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        objRequest.Timeout = Timeout;
        objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        ...
```

And things started working.

Answer (score 0):

No need to purchase an SSL. But you can upgrade your certificate into SHA 256 and TLS 1.2. Refer to the link below.

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913

and

https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update